# Java, write to file with headings

Tags: java, file, writetofile

I have this method that takes one `String` and writes it to a file. I set the `PrintWriter` to true because I want to save all the data that is written to it.

I want to have headings on this file. How can I write the headlines to the file and only do it one time?

My method looks like this:

```
public static void writeToFile(String text) {

    try {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test", true); 
        writer.write(text);


        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant Headlines.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand DYM. I just need simple text like name, nuber, date etc printed on the top of the file and under ther I will print my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether your file has multiple heading or not. Assuming your file has only one heading we can do this as follow -

**1.** Since your file contain heading only one time, you can check whether the file is accessing for the first time  -

```
File f = new File(//your file name);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
  //write heading
}
```

**2.** If the file is first time accessed then you can add a header -

```
String heading = "Some heading";
```

The full code looks like -

```
public static void writeToFile(String text) {

    String heading = "Some heading";

    try {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f, true); 

        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
          writer.write(heading);
       } 

        writer.write(text);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }finally{
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the full code right? It is checking if the file exists after opening it for write so I think you will find it always exist. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferWriter to write a sentence and take a look at a better way to handle the file.

```
try {

        String content = "This is the content to write into file";

        File f = new File("test.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
    writer.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit so 'try' is formatted.You should close the file with finally like Razib did so it closes no matter there is an exception or not.